How to capture TPMS FSK signal on MT38220301?
I'm working on a project using MT38220301, which is a TPMS (Tire Pressure Monitoring System).

I have TPMS Trigger Unit and a CMOSTEK CM2300A for capture and decode FSK Signals, which need exact frame Preamble and sync for data to be captured correctly, otherwise no data received.

According to datasheet Chinese supplier send me the message format is like this below, but I capture nothing.

What should I do to capture signals? Am I Need a better capturing device? Or Any body has a hint for me how to set parameters correctly?

I asked this question in electronics.stackexchange
because it is an electronic question not mechanical. I dont know why they move it to this not related forum?!?!

Hint?: I think this is more of a software question, rather than an electrical or mechanical question. Here's source for an Android App, that is recently updated, just compile and sideload to your phone: https://github.com/VincentMasselis/TPMS-advanced - You can also pick through other projects to see the format of the data, if you insist on rolling your own: https://github.com/jboone/tpms https://github.com/andi38/TPMS
